# Woocommerce use if statement on checkout page

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

Need a little help please. I'm working on a Woocommerce site. On the checkout page for individual products i would want to issue an if statement based on that item's price.

Something like this:

if ( $_this_item_price > 30){

echo 'blah blah blah' } else{ echo ' something else'}

I'd want the statement to be around that item's price. And also where should I paste the code. The file structure of WP confuses me.

Thanks a lot in advance. Bless!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and we can help you improve it. Otherwise, this is just a "please do my homework." type question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function inside your function.php

```
     add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'wnd_checkout_message', 100 );
            function wnd_checkout_message( ) {
             foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                    $item = $cart_item['data'];

             if ( $item->sale_price  > 30  )    {
                echo "somthing";

             }else{
              echo 'another thing ';
            }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kashalo. I'm so grateful. It worked. Bless!